# How to use dgrid3d with X and Y points to plot an intensity map

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with X Y data points (> 10^4)

```
12.399999999999999  3.7333333333333334
22.13333333333334   34.93333333333333
13.600000000000001  10.133333333333333
94.26666666666667   26.
25.333333333333336  8.666666666666666
52. 38.
25.33333333333333   51.733333333333334
24.799999999999997  37.333333333333336
77.33333333333333   5.466666666666667
13.2    7.733333333333333
33.46666666666667   4.666666666666667
33.86666666666666   46.
52.8    3.466666666666667
24.400000000000002  20.933333333333334
54.53333333333334   27.6
121.73333333333335  30.133333333333333
103.73333333333333  13.466666666666667
47.599999999999994  5.333333333333333
...........
```

(positive and non-gridded), which I would like to plot with Gnuplot.

I have been looking different posts and examples, and they provide a function for the intensity or directly the Z values corresponding to the intensity, or they use an array of values indicating pixels or squared zones of an image.

I would like to ask if there is a way to plot an intensity map plot providing only the X and Y points. Also, I would like to know if it is possible to indicate the range to plot and the granularity (the bin size or the interpolation order).

Thank you very much for the help

**EDIT (based on Comments)**

I have tried set size square

```
set autoscale fix
unset key
set view map
set xrange [0:200]
set yrange [0:200]
set dgrid3d 10,10,4
splot "data.dat" w pm3d
```

Gnuplot tells me that I need a third column with the weights.
I have no third column in my dataset, just the X and Y values.
How could I correctly use `dgrid3d`, and plot an intensity map or frequency map of my points?

Note: My Gnuplot is version 5.2, and there is an option **bin** which can be used to bin x values, but I do not know if it can bin 2D points too

Comment: Use `set dgrid3d` with appropriate settings

Comment: @Christoph Thank you very much. That is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Christoph I am testing with my data set X Y values and I can not get a result. I am going tp edit this post with the Gnuplot code.